# How to query with greater than less than condition using StrongLoop-Loopback explorer?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I've been trying to figure out how to perform a simple where condition using greater than or less than using StrongLoop/Loopback. Official documentation states to use the following format:

```
{"where": {"id": {"gt": 45} } }
```

But the Response is showing no content. The sql query return 55 records.

Please refer the image. Is there any way to get the desired result? Kindly help...

[image: Response of the where condition query]

Comment: This query is ok. Can you post your model definition and do you have any operation hook or remote hook that intercepts query operation?

Comment: No, there is no operation hook or remote hook. I've not yet gone so far, learning my way through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine. I tried to reproduce it, but it works properly for me. Please post a sample repo so I can clone it and try to reproduce it from your use case. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Reporting-issues#bug-report.

Comment: Thanks! But I managed to do the same in new project. I don't know what went wrong, but after I created new project and it is working fine. I guess the result was brought from cache.

Comment: Weird. Well if you run into more issues, just create a repo with steps to reproduce and I will try to take a look. Please include the output from `slc -v` and your node version.

Comment: Great, thanks for the support. More questions coming this way!